# How to do animation like app launch when you tap on the app icon on iOS homescreen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-animation, uicollectionview

I wants to do animation something similar to app launch on the ios home screen. Like the whole collection view goes to scale up and the launched app covered the whole screen.

I am using the iOS 7 new api for viewcontroller transitions.
And I am using the parent collection viewcontroller snapshot to appropriate animation.
But still I am not getting enough like what animation is actually is happening at that time?

Answer (score 1):

To get the performance and look you want, you may have to perform transforms on the view layers.

I put up a little demo on [GitHub](https://github.com/picciano/CollectionViewLaunchAnimation), but the relevant code is below.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCellView *cell = (MyCellView *)[self collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.detailViewController.labelString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row];
    [self.view.superview addSubview:self.detailViewController.view];

    // tap position relative to collection view
    float screenX = self.collectionView.frame.origin.x + cell.center.x;
    float screenY = self.collectionView.frame.origin.y + cell.center.y - self.collectionView.contentOffset.y;

    // tap position relative to view frame
    float translateX = (self.view.frame.size.width / -2.0) + screenX;
    float translateY = (self.view.frame.size.height / -2.0) + screenY;

    CATransform3D transform_detail = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DMakeTranslation(translateX, translateY, 0.0), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    CATransform3D transform_main = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-translateX * 5.0, -translateY * 5.0, 0.0), 5.0, 5.0, 5.0);

    self.detailViewController.view.layer.transform = transform_detail;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.detailViewController.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        self.view.layer.transform = transform_main;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you add the reverse animation like "when you tap on home button and app goes to background" in your sample project on github? Or maybe you can give a small hint here only.

Comment: You would just reverse the animation...that is for the detailView you would transform from CATransform3DIdentity to the "transform_detail". The main view would go from "transform_main" to CATransform3DIdentity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom segues.

[This](http://blog.dadabeatnik.com/2013/10/13/custom-segues/) tutorial should help you and below is the code excerpt.

```
- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    // Add the destination view as a subview, temporarily
    [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];

    // Transformation start scale
    destinationViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05);

    // Store original centre point of the destination view
    CGPoint originalCenter = destinationViewController.view.center;
    // Set center to start point of the button
    destinationViewController.view.center = self.originatingPoint;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         // Grow!
                         destinationViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
                         destinationViewController.view.center = originalCenter;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [destinationViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; // remove from temp super view
                         [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:NULL]; // present VC
                     }];
}
```